# Character is stored inplace of an integer

Tags: c, struct, scanf

Character is stored in place of an integer

```
    /* C program to find strong number using Structure and Pointers*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct strg {
    long int a;
}*strgvar;

int strong(int);

int main() {
    int result;
    strgvar = (struct strg*) malloc(sizeof(struct strg));
    printf("Enter the number ...\n");
    scanf("%ld", &strgvar -> a);
    result = strong(strgvar -> a);
    if(result == strgvar->a) {
        printf("Its a strong number !");
    }
    else {
        printf("Its not a strong number !");
    }
    return 0;
}   

int strong (int a) {
    int fact, r, n, sum = 0;
    while(a != 0) {
        r = r % 10;
        for(int i =0; i <= r; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        sum = sum + fact;
        n = n/ 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

While running this program , the input integer is not storing in the variable.But while entering any character it prints "Its a strong number!"

Example:

> case 1:
>
> Enter the number... 234
>
> 2
>
> 178
>
> er
>
> fg yu8 . case 2: Enter the number ...e

Its a strong number!

Comment: First check the result of `scanf`. It returns the number of successful conversions. If the result is 0, something is wrong and `strgvar->a` remains uninitialized.

Comment: Also you are doing `r = r % 10;` with an uninitialized `r`. The result of `strong` is undefined. What exactly is `strong` doing?

Answer (score 1):

The loop in `strong` is obviously infinite unless `a==0` to start.  If `scanf` fails, `strgvar->a` is left *uninitialized*, so your program has *undefined behavior*.  One “reasonable” possibility is that the value is read as 0, which produces the observed result.